# In Notepad++ is there a regex capable of taking what's to the right of "::" and moving it to the left of "::" but without the apostrophe?

Tags: regex, text, notepad++

So in short, I have a text file containing a bunch of contractions in English, 3 of which are below and one that was done before I realized how arduous it would be for about 80 lines.

```
::I'd've
::I'll
::ain't
dont::don't
```

Normally I use RegEx to modify most of my text files via n++ but find it lacking in this scenario. I was essentially wanting to take what's to the right of the `::`, move it to the left of `::`, and remove the apostrophes `'` ignoring those already done.

```
Idve::I'd've
Ill::I'll
aint::ain't
dont::don't
```

I'm still in the early stages of learning/using regex, and I'm barely competent at any programming outside of AutoHotkey, if you would call that real programming (at least at my level). Would regex+notepad++ be able to fulfill this request or would I want to use something like Python or Bash to modify the text file?

`^[^:]*$` is the only regex I've used and I found that one online as I couldn't figure out how to solve the problem for `NOT :` (to add `::` to the beginning of the line) but stumbled there in applying it to only the lines not containing a `::` already.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the limit of how many apostrophes there can be per line, you may create a regex that will match `::` at the start of a line, and then any number of chars other than linebreak chars, `:` and `'`, captured into a group, and then a `'`, and repeat this subpattern in a sequence of optional non-capturing groups. Then, replace with backreferences to the groups. You may have as many as 99 groups using the `$nn` syntax.

Here is a regex supporting up to 9 apostrophes per line:

```
^::([^:\r\n']+)'(?:([^:\r\n']+)')?(?:([^:\r\n']+)')?(?:([^:\r\n']+)')?(?:([^:\r\n']+)')?(?:([^:\r\n']+)')?(?:([^:\r\n']+)')?(?:([^:\r\n']+)')?([^:\r\n']+)?
```

Replace with `$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$0`.

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `::` - a `::` string
- `([^:\r\n']+)'` - Group 1 (`$1`): one or more chars other than `:`, CR, LF, `'`, then a `'` char is matched
- `(?:([^:\r\n']+)')?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

  - `([^:\r\n']+)'` - Group 2 (`$2`): one or more chars other than `:`, CR, LF, `'`
  - `'` - a `'`
- `(?:([^:\r\n']+)')?` - Group 3 (`$3`) in an optional non-capturing group
- `(?:([^:\r\n']+)')?` - Group 4 (`$4`) in an optional non-capturing group
- `(?:([^:\r\n']+)')?` - Group 5 (`$5`) in an optional non-capturing group
- `(?:([^:\r\n']+)')?` - Group 6 (`$6`) in an optional non-capturing group
- `(?:([^:\r\n']+)')?` - Group 7 (`$7`) in an optional non-capturing group
- `(?:([^:\r\n']+)')?` - Group 8 (`$8`) in an optional non-capturing group
- `([^:\r\n']+)?` - an optional capturing group 9 (`$9`): one or more chars other than `:`, CR, LF, `'`.

Note that `$0` refers to the whole match value.

Comment: areyouawizard.jpg - it worked exactly how I'd imagined! Is the use of \1 vs $1 for referencing capture groups the same for notepad++'s regex engine, or is this something relatively universal?

Comment: @stone_orb Not sure what you mean. Backreferences are used everywhere in regex replace functions. `$n` and `$nn` difference from ``\n`` is also quite universal, but since ``\n`` are POSIX, `$n` and `$nn` are only available in NFA regexes (NP++ uses NFA, Boost regex).